# General question about convergence of improper integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I know that in order to prove that $ \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right) $ is convergent, I have to show that both $ \intop_{-\infty}^{a}f\left(x\right),\intop_{a}^{\infty}f\left(x\right) $ for some $ a \in \mathbb{R} $.

Is it true also for :

$ \intop_{-\infty}^{0}f\left(x\right) $ for $ f(x) $  that isn't bounded around $ 0 $ ?

I mean, in order to show that $ \intop_{-\infty}^{0}f\left(x\right) $ is convergent, I have to show that $ \intop_{-\infty}^{a}f\left(x\right),\intop_{a}^{0}f\left(x\right) $ both convergent for some $ a<0 $ ? and even if just one of them divergent, it means that the whole integral $ \intop_{-\infty}^{0}f\left(x\right) $ is divergent ?

I can't understand it, because for instance, if $ \intop_{-\infty}^{a}f\left(x\right)=-\infty $ and $ \intop_{a}^{0}f\left(x\right)=\infty $, there is a chance that $ \intop_{a}^{0}f\left(x\right)+\intop_{-\infty}^{a}f\left(x\right) $ will be a real number.

A clarification of this subject would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the original statement is correct?  It looks like the question you raise means that "some a" should be "all a".

Comment: @obliv As i said, f(x) isnt bounded around 0, ao we will have to take 2 limits here.

Comment: yup my bad @Waizman

Comment: @herb steinberg Im assuming f(x) is integrable in any closed segment that isnt contain the bounds, so any a I would pick would work.

Comment: $\lim_{b\to -\infty} \intop_{b}^{0}f(x) = F(0) - F(b)$ + $\lim_{c\to 0^{-}} \intop_{a}^{c}f(x) = F(a) - F(c)$ I guess if you wanted to find a convergent value in this case you'd have to know the antiderivative or this gets more complicated